# Why it is prohibited for Muslims to enter a building with images and statues?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, malaikah, image, caliph

While going through the below question:

[Can social functions be booked in a Church?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39549/can-social-functions-be-booked-in-a-church)

> I stumbled upon this Hadith:
>
> Ibn ‘Aa’idh narrated in Futooh al-Shaam that when ‘Umar came to Syria,
> the Christians made food for him and called him, and he said: Where is
> it? They said: In the church, and he refused to go. He said to ‘Ali:
> Take the people to eat lunch. So ‘Ali took the people and entered the
> church, and he and the people ate lunch, and ‘Ali looked at the images
> and said: **What would be wrong if the Ameer al-Mu’mineen entered this
> place?** Al-Mughni (8/113).

My question is whether the question of Ali (RA) was ever answered? Do we know why it is prohibited for Muslims to enter a building with images and statues?

I am aware of the prohibition for angels but this is the first time I read w.r.t humans (muslims).

A tafsir would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not prohibited for Muslims and the statements and opinions saying so can easily be rejected. One of them actually is the quote in your post if we add the commentary of ibn Qudamah to it.

Comment: If you have the translated commentary of ibn Qudamah at hand, please do share it. It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: the issue is that ibn Qudamah quotes from a no more existing source ibn 'A'idh's al-Futuh a-Shamiya does not exist in a printed version if it still exist at all. I've posted a link to al-Mughni under the answer of the question you refer to. And even by reading that fatwa you may come to the conclusion that the hanbalis view and that of ibn Qudamah is clearly saying the existence of images doesn't matter at all be it in a church or a house to enter it for a Muslim. The statement of 'Ali only expresses a wondering why 'Omar would refuse being there to eat with the people.

Comment: I was not able to locate the story in al-Waqidi's version of the futuh. Al-Waqidi apprenty was the teacher of  ibn 'A'idh. At the moment my first concern is to find the sources in Arabic. islamqa in a [newer fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/244710/ruling-on-using-the-church-as-a-hall-for-activities-for-muslim-children) added two words to the quote as it seems.

Comment: The tradition you have quoted is actually cited by the Hanbalis as proof that is **not** prohibited. Because if it was haram, then how could Umar instruct or even allow the Muslims to do it? Rather it was obligatory on him to prevent them.